# Using method from base to create an object gives error unable to cast

Tags: c#

I have classes with protected constructors and a public static create method. I already have such a method in the base class. Is it possible to use it in a child class?
Right now I have:

Base class:

```
public class Screening : CandidateEvent
{
    protected Screening() { }
    protected Screening(Guid id) : base(id) { }
    public static Screening Create(DateTime plannedDate, PeriodDateTime period, String summary)
    {
        Screening screening = new Screening(Guid.NewGuid());
        screening.PlannedDate = plannedDate;
        screening.Period = period;
        screening.Summary = summary;
        // checks the params
        return screening;
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class EmailScreening : Screening
{
    protected EmailScreening() { }
    protected EmailScreening(Guid id) : base(id) { }
    public new static EmailScreening Create(DateTime plannedDate, PeriodDateTime period, String summary)
    {
        EmailScreening emailScreening = (EmailScreening)Screening.Create(plannedDate, period, summary);
        return emailScreening;
    }
}
```

And test:

```
[TestClass]
public class EmailScreeningTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCreate()
    {
        PeriodDateTime period = new PeriodDateTime(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01), new DateTime(2017, 02, 02));
        EmailScreening emailscreening = EmailScreening.Create(new DateTime(2017,11,05), period, "summary");

        Assert.AreEqual(emailscreening.PlannedDate, new DateTime(2017, 11, 05));
        Assert.AreEqual(emailscreening.Period, period);
        Assert.AreEqual(emailscreening.Summary, "summary");
    }  
}
```

But the test fails saying Unable to cast object of type 'Screening' to type 'EmailScreening'.

So, is there a way to use the base method in my child classes and obtain the right object?

Comment: Well yes, `Screening.Create` (which is called by `EmailScreening.Create`) just creates an instance of `Screening`, not of `EmailScreening`. You can't cast that to `EmailScreening`, because it's simply *not* an `EmailScreening`.

Comment: Even if you made `Create` generic so that it could "know" what actual type you wanted to create, there's no means of using it as you want to here since the only constructor you can ask for on a generic type is a parameterless one.

Comment: Thank you Jon, That is what I understood from my searches as well. Is there a way to use the base method and get the right object? Or do I have to create the method for each child, without using the base?

Comment: Thank you Damien, So I take it I have to create methods for each child, no way of using the base one?

Comment: @Tina Yes you have to do that.  You cannot re-use the base method because it creates a `Screening` instance.  What you could do is have a `Setup(Screening aScreening)` method in your base class which performs the setup only (everything without the call to `... new Screening ...`) and then re-use that in derived classes.

Comment: Thank you very much Viktor. I did as you said and it works. It also saves me having to write the same thing over and over again. Thank you